# New intent,application restarts

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

from my first class (infoWifiActivity.class) i want to call the second one(Netdetails.class).

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(InfoWifiActivity.this,Netdetails.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

in my manifest i added this

```
<activity
    android:name=".Netdetails"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="my.infoWifi.Netdetails" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

exactly above the .
But everytime the application restarts.Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were looking for ACTION_MAIN:

```
<activity
  android:name=".Netdetails"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the whole

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

from your xml.

Comment: the problem was on the "onStop()" method.I used the System.exit(0); and it was doing the loop.Thank you very much for your time.